# PHP: Making an age range

Tags: php

If i would like to have an age range in my search form.

From: [input] to [input] years, so there you type e.g 18 to 26, how later can i use the fields and sort by a age range, in a query select.

```
<td>
    <input name="MinAge" maxlength="2" id="MinAge" style="width: 40px;" type="text">
</td>
<td style="width: 40px; text-align: center;">
    <span id="MinAge_label">years</span>&nbsp; to 
</td>
<td>
    <input name="MaxAge" maxlength="2" id="MaxAge" style="width: 40px;" type="text">&nbsp;<span id="MaxAge_label">years</span>
</td>
```

Comment: Do you know that there’s a [`LABEL` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL)?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking for. Please explain a little better.
I can only see one input to start with but you're talking as if there's two!

Comment: Updated question. I am asking for to make a query that shows all rows that has the age column between of what you enter. Example 18 and 26, then it will display all rows that has 18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26 in the age column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't "sort" by range... I assume you mean filter?

```
$min = (int) $_POST['MinAge'];
$max = (int) $_POST['MaxAge'];
```

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE age BETWEEN $min AND $max ORDER BY age
```

Comment: Shouldn't the SQL end with `ORDER BY age`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've perhaps not posted the correct code from your sample, but I suspect you're looking for something like the following;

```
<tr>
  <td><label for="minAge">Minimum Age:</label></td>
  <td><input name="minAge" id="minAge" maxlength="2" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><label for="maxAge">Maximum Age:</label></td>
  <td><input name="maxAge" id="maxAge" maxlength="2" /></td>
</tr>
```

You will then want to use these values in your SQL Query. Assuming that you are using MySQL, you will probably then want something like the following;

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE age >= ':minAge' AND age <= ':maxAge'
```

Where you would then bind the minimum age and maximum age to the :minAge, :maxAge parameters in your SQL statement.